# in Notion, How do I show the sum of values based on project status?

Tags: notion

In notion I want to achieve this:

I have two databases one is Project with field "Value", which is connected to another database called "incomes".

So if project has status completed formula must show sum of values which has status completed. otherwise it must show nothing.

How to achieve that?